# HighChart: Show custom label on series (spline)

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, timeserieschart

I have a monthly chart (made in highcharts), with two SPLINE Series in it. I want to add random text (in random place based on the series) for the series in the chart, How can I achieve this.

[image: Original chart]

I would like it to look like this.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Renderer](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.text) which allows to add text in any place in the chart.